# Interpolation: replace zeros with intermediate values

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have an array in MATLAB

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0094, ...]
```

The data has non-zero values at intervals of about nine or ten, and all other values are zero.

How could I replace the zeros with some interpolated values? I don't want stepped data.

For example:

```
% Data set 
A = [0  0  0  4  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 13];
% Desired output
A = [1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data, using the code formatting available is much clearer, easier for others to copy and often more concise. I've sorted the formatting out for you here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the main steps for approaching this problem:

- Treat your input data as the `y` data for interpolation.
- Treat the indices of each data point as the `x` data for interpolation.
- Use `interp1` to linearly interpolate from an the non-zero elements (`x` and `y` data) to the full `x` axis (`1:numel(data)`).
- Use extrapolation so that the initial values are populated even if the first or last input values aren't known.

Example:

```
% Input
data = [ 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 13 ];
% Set up x and y values for interpolation
x = find( data ~= 0 );
y = data( x );
% output
data = interp1( x, y, 1:numel(data), 'linear', 'extrap' );
% >> data = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13];
```

Of course this could be done in one line if you don't declare `x` and `y` first.